# How to center the start menu along with the taskbar icons in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

I am using a Windows 10 (1909) PC and I don’t want to update to Windows 11 (since my PC is unsupported).

Is there a way to center the start button or the entire menu to center of the taskbar. I have searched the Internet and the articles just shows how to align the icons to the center of the screen.  If this is possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no method for centering the Start button.

Centering the taskbar icons is easy, where normally the method is to
add an empty toolbar on the left, in order to "push" the icons to the
right.

However, no easy solution exists for the Start button, except perhaps
by its replacement by a third-party product.

An example is
[Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/)
(commercial with trial), which (at least according to its screenshots)
can recreate it in the middle of the taskbar.

Comment: start 11 is paid I think and I don't want to pay for any software Thank you for your reply and I am marking your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 11 concept is called a Launcher, and the start menu and taskbar were written in a completely new way (from what I have read).

The Windows 11 taskbar is pretty much fixed in way it works: does not support right click context or toolbars and does not split across display screens very well.

Windows 10 does not natively support the Windows 11 taskbar concept and you cannot natively move icons to the center.

There are 3rd party tools you can try. One of the most popular is Start11 (as Harry noted).

You are probably best advised to use Windows 10 as it is until time to replace the computer.  I replaced my desktop computer with a Windows 11 computer but I have not replaced my laptop computer which will not run Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native method in Windows 10 to center taskbar icons. You will need to use a third-party tool (or perform a few manual modifications to system files, which I don't recommend).

One such third-party tool is [TaskbarX](https://chrisandriessen.nl/taskbarx) ([source code](https://github.com/ChrisAnd1998/TaskbarX)). You can download the software free of charge through its website/GitHub or pay if you download via the [Microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/taskbarx/9pcmz6bxk8gh?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,I think that TaskbarX only center the icons not the start menu itself

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't really read your question properly. Looks like there's several requests in that repo to add Start button centering, so the author is aware of users wanting that feature. Perhaps in the future. This other project might be what you're after: [https://github.com/JustIntroverted/TaskbarCustomizer/](https://github.com/JustIntroverted/TaskbarCustomizer/)